# Call ((Double)->())? in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a library to do rating as stars,so I'm trying to get a reference of : `public var didFinishTouchingCosmos: ((Double)->())?`

in my view controller i got a reference of view like :

```
@IBOutlet var raitingView: CosmosView!
var rating : Double?
```

Then in my view controller viewDidLoad i start using it this way :

```
raitingView.didFinishTouchingCosmos{rating in
        }
```

but I'm getting an error `cannot call value of non-function type`((double) ->())?

The library link is here : https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function this way. Actually this is a very basic syntax you can check from the introduction to Swift from apple. I recommend you to read the Swift tutorial from Apple through iBook Store. They are free.

```
raitingView.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { rating in 
    // Do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is like this

Comment: Sorry I thought it is a function not a variable. I edited my answer

Comment: I did misread the example in their tests. Your version is the correct one, I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, define the handlers `raitingView.didCosmos` and `raitingView.didFinishTouchingCosmos` as function handlers, as shown in [this demo](https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos/blob/master/Demo/ViewController.swift).

Comment: Yea this is kind of confusing because this kind of function is declared as a delegate.

Comment: @JasonNam Just a note: it's not a delegate, per se, just a function assigned to a property (that have the type of a closure). E.g., we may assign the function `func foo() { print("bar") }` to a variable, `let myFooClosure = foo`, and this variable will be inferred to be a of type `() -> ()`, i.e., a closure. Delegates, on the other hand, are generally instances of heterogeneous protocols, used to delegate responsibilities of the instance it lives in (e.g. a class instance) to an instance of another type.

Comment: Ya, I mean the property in the question is not a delegate but usually this kind of things is declared as a delegate method. I think that's why it is a little bit confusing haha :)

Comment: Oh, i was away from work ! i see now this is the way to call, i understood now !